# What's the best way to create exchangeable tuple keys for the same dictionary value?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

```
def check():
    dict_choice_a = {(a, b) : value, (b, a) : value}  #(a, b) and (b, a) refer to the same value but repeted
    dict_choice_b = {tuple(sorted((a, b)) : value}  #not repetitive but unreadable
    dict_choice_a[(a, b)] = new_value #need to do twice to change value but more readable than dict_choice_b
    dict_choice_a[(b, a)] = new_value

    #value of both keys are always the same
```

I want to create a `dictionary` that has tuple keys referred to its values, that keys need to be exchangeable as `(a, b) = (b, a)` and they only refer to the same value.

Here's the question is: what is the best way to make the element of tulpe of keys exchangeable but also refer to the same value.

Moreover, string should be also work in the solution.

Comment: you can use `set` instead of `tuple`

Comment: @Ni. `frozenset`, `set`s aren't hashable so can't be keys

Comment: right, good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the comments, you can put `a` and `b` into a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which is unordered:

```
dict_choice = {frozenset((a, b)): value}
```

---

If you need this to be automatic, you could create your own [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping):

```
class MyDict(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        self._map = {}
        if arg is not None:
            self.update(arg)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._map[frozenset(key)]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._map[frozenset(key)] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._map[frozenset(key)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._map)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._map)
```

In use:

```
>>> d = MyDict([((1, 2), 'hello'), ((3, 4), 'world')])
>>> d[(2, 1)]
'hello'
```

However note that this could have unexpected behaviour with other kinds of keys:

```
>>> d['hello'] = 'world'
>>> d['hole']
'world'
>>> d[1] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "python", line 14, in __setitem__
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @jonrsharpe solution, I created an alternative for the unexpected behavior with other kinds of keys, considered that only tuples will be used in an unordered way:

```
class MyDict(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        self._map = {}
        if arg is not None:
            self.update(arg)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            return self._map[frozenset(key)]
        return self._map[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            self._map[frozenset(key)] = value
        else:
            self._map[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            del self._map[frozenset(key)]
        else:
            del self.map[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._map)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._map)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._map)
```